# MYSQL - Fetch most recent result if it matches string (NOT fetch most-recent result that matches string)

Tags: mysql

**Goal**: query MySQL DB looking for the most-recent stock status of an item and return a result ONLY IF status = 'out_of_stock'.

Also, return the result only if the item is found in a specific brand's table (I think I have this part down, see query below).

I do *not* want to return the most-recent instance where the item was out of stock - primarily because this will just tell me the last time it was out of stock, but not if it's been in stock since then.

I've been fighting this task for the past few days and I feel like I'm stuck - maybe I'm not looking in the right places, or searching for the right thing, but I can't find an answer.

Current query that I tried to cobble together (doesn't work properly):

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(C.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d'))) as Date, B.product_id, B.status, oos_level FROM (
  SELECT MAX(A.status) as status, A.product_id, COUNT(*) as oos_level
  FROM logs.actions A
  WHERE A.product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM nyc_ro.product_list)
  GROUP BY A.product_id) 
AS B
INNER JOIN logs.actions C
ON B.product_id = C.product_id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') >= FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 30 DAY
AND B.status = 'out_of_stock' 
GROUP BY product_id, status
ORDER BY Date DESC, product_id DESC
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!